# Problema com Bindind + KeyDown C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Tenho no XAML um combobox e um textbox, sendo eles:

```
                <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Tipo Filtro" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TipoFiltroSQL, Mode = TwoWay}" Name="CmbTipoFiltro" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="16" Content="Filtro" Grid.Column="4"  Grid.Row="0" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Name="TextFiltro" Text = "{Binding Path=FiltroConsulta, Mode = TwoWay}" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="16"  Grid.Column="4"  Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" KeyUp="FiltroTextChangedEventHandler" />
```

Observe que nesse momento estou usando KeyUp para captar a tecla, mas já tentei várias outras coisas.

E o método FiltroTextChangedEventHandler:

```
private void FiltroTextChangedEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valor TexBox: " + TextFiltro);
        Console.WriteLine("Tipo Consulta: "+Bean.TipoFiltroSQL);
        Console.WriteLine("Valor: " + Bean.FiltroConsulta);
        Bean.CarregaListaFiltro();
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente Localizados: " + Bean.Lista.Count);
        updateDataContext();
    }
```

No caso esse textbox é bindado com a seguinte String:

```
public String FiltroConsulta { get; set; }
```

Quando digito qualquer caracter ele aparece no textbox e em seguida ele é apagado, no console aparece a seguinte situação:

```
Valor TexBox: System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: p
Tipo Consulta: INICIA_COM
Valor: 
Cliente Localizados: 3
```

no updateDataContext eu faço o seguinte:

```
private void updateDataContext()
    {
        this.DataContext = null;
        this.DataContext = Bean;
    }
```

observe que a letra "P" está no textbox, porem o valor com a string com o binding aparece vazia, alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: Você já está implementando o [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)?